# How to login SAML Request with Curl

Tags: php, curl, saml

I can't go to the login page without redirection because give me some fail. The login is a SAML request with SSO.

I'm trying to access a web which gives me authentication access. When using the browser, this website redirects to a login page. If logged in, you are redirected to the page I want to see. Unfortunately, I haven't achieved this redirect with curl, resulting in this response

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
</head>

<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF"
    onload="var url=window.location.hash;if(url&&0!==url.length){var anchorCookie='oucrsqkpislglxzpbqnbaidpi_anchor=&quot;'+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&quot;';anchorCookie=anchorCookie+'; Secure; SameSite=None';document.cookie=anchorCookie}document.forms[0].submit()">
    <p>
        <script language="javascript">
            document.write("Please wait ...");
        </script>
    </p><noscript>
        <p>Note: Your browser does not support JavaScript or it is turned off. Press the button to proceed.</p>
    </noscript>
    <form method="post" action="https://this is the redirect web">
        <input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="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"/><input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="oucrsqkpislglxzpbqnbaidpi"/><noscript><input type="submit" value="Continue"/></noscript>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

In addition, I can't access to the redirect page(login page) without the redirection.